# "Scale" does not work with Font Awesome

Tags: luatex, fontawesome

I use "Open Sans" and "Font Awesome" with LuaLaTeX a lot. I can scale Open Sans as expected, but I *can not* scale Font Awesome:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{parskip}

\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Open Sans} % Scale works
\fontspec{FontAwesome}[Scale=3.0]  % Scale DOES NOT work

\begin{document}

\makebox[1cm][l]{\faPhone} Test \\
\makebox[1cm][l]{\faExternalLink} Test \\
\makebox[1cm][l]{\faEnvelopeO} Test \\

\end{document}
```

How do I scale Font Awesome? The best solution for me would be to set one "scale factor" fpr the whole document. Can I do that?

THX a lot!

Regards

Thorsten

Answer (score 1):

\fontspec is the wrong command, it is like e.g. \huge or \sffamily meant for local font changes. If you want to change the font for the whole document change the underlying font family:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Open Sans} % Scale works
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}[Scale=3.0]  % Scale DOES NOT work

\begin{document}

\makebox[1cm][l]{\faPhone} Test \\
\makebox[1cm][l]{\faExternalLink} Test \\
\makebox[1cm][l]{\faEnvelopeO} Test \\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aaahhhh, ok, thanks a lot! I kind of missunderstood the fontspec documentation. But MatchLowercase and MatchUppercase as an argument for Scale still does not work. Isn't it supposed to work that way?

Comment: fontawesome doesn't have the necessary fontdimens, and as it hasn't an x or X either fontspec can't calculate them.

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite easy to add a `scaled` option to `fontawesome`, but, alas, the author of the package didn't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\ifdefined\FA
  % we're in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \LetLtxMacro\origFA\FA
  \renewcommand{\FA}{\fontsize{\FAsize}{0}\origFA}
\else
  % pdflatex
  \preto\FAone{\fontsize{\FAsize}{0}}
  \preto\FAtwo{\fontsize{\FAsize}{0}}
  \preto\FAthree{\fontsize{\FAsize}{0}}
\fi
\newcommand{\FAsize}{30}% <---- set here the font size you want

\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Open Sans} % Scale works

\begin{document}

\makebox[1cm][l]{\faPhone} Test \\
\makebox[1cm][l]{\faExternalLink} Test \\
\makebox[1cm][l]{\faEnvelopeO} Test \\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THX! Ulrike's solution is easier for me. But maybe I'll suggest your improvement to the package maintainer.... :-)

Comment: @Tom7320 I'd better see a `scaled` option that can be realized in a different way.

Comment: That's true! I agree!